# How to calculate accuracy of prediction?

Tags: python, classification, prediction, knn

I have created an excel from a dataset that includes some parameters for classfication. Then, i have created a test dataset and i've classified these data. Now, i have predictions for all test data but how can i find accuracy of this predictions?

```
df = pd.read_excel(r"excellocation")
df_model = df.copy()
scaler = StandardScaler()
features =  [[feature1,feature2......]]
for feature in features:
    df_model[feature] = scaler.fit_transform(df_model[feature])
knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
x = df_model.drop(columns=['class'],1)
y = df_model['class']
knn.fit(x, y)
clf= neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier()
clf.fit(x,y)
for example in test_data:
     prediction = clf.predict(example)
#####i need accuracy of this prediction
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is:

```
preds = clf.predict(test_data)
accuracy = np.mean(preds == test_data)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But i have many calculation before prediction step. Also, i need accuracy for each prediction. Do you know a way?

Comment: As I showed `accuracy = np.mean(preds==true_data)`